# keeping the state of checkbox after submitting page.PHP

Tags: php

I want the page to show the previously entered data in its place as it was before page submitted.I did this for the two text fields but not able to do for the checkbox.keeping the state of checkbox after submitting page.

```
      <?php 

         $params=$_POST;
         // param keys
         $pk = array('name','email','rating');
         foreach($pk as $param_name)
         {
               if(!isset($params[$param_name]))
               {
                     $params[$param_name] = '';
               }
         }
     ?>
     <html>
     <form method="POST">
             Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $params['name']; ?>" /><br/>
             Email:<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $params['email']; ?>"/><br/>
             Rating:<?php if( isset( $params['rating'] ) && !empty( $params['rating'] ) ) { 
         $CH = count($params['rating']);
         for( $i=1; $i<=5; $i++ ) 
                 {
        if( $CH < $i) 
                    { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="rating[]" value="1">
              <?php }  else 
                    { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="rating[]" value="1" CHECKED>
              <?php }
        } 
         } else { 
            for( $i=1; $i<=5; $i++ ) {?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rating[]" value="1" >
            <?php   }
        ?>
      </form>
      </html>
```

Comment: What’s the actual problem then? You know what HTML code is required for a checked checkbox, right? Well then generate it dynamically, based on the values you are given.

Comment: can you please explain how to do that? please take my post to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<?php 
foreach(range(1, 5) as $rating){ 

    $checked = null;

    if( isset($_POST['rating']) && is_array($_POST['rating']) && in_array($rating, $_POST['rating']) ){
        $checked = ' checked';
    }
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rating[]" value="<?php echo $rating; ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?>>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i applied your code, what happens is the check boxes are unchecked initially then as i check some checkboxes and submit the page,all the checkboxes gets checked when the page appears

Comment: @user3045432 Did you change all values to 1 or something?